Multiple GoTrueClient instances detected in the same browser context with supabase and javascript
I don't understand this problem/warning. Code written yesterday worked perfectly fine and when changed to add some PHP script functionality for sending emails which didn't turn out great, I undo-ed all changes I've made but code then started showing the following warning and it won't update my Supabase.

Multiple GoTrueClient instances detected in the same browser context. It is not an error, but this should be avoided as it may produce undefined behavior when used concurrently under the same storage key.

This code worked without any problems yesterday, I just need solution on how to fix this GoTrueClient thing and what exactly is that.
<script>
    async function loadCalendarTable() {
        const url = 'https://kvxswebzyfogzgiclagy.supabase.co';
        const key = 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJzdXBhYmFzZSIsInJlZiI6Imt2eHN3ZWJ6eWZvZ3pnaWNsYWd5Iiwicm9sZSI6ImFub24iLCJpYXQiOjE3MDg0NjA5NDcsImV4cCI6MjAyNDAzNjk0N30.hLJFmnkA-2oNgXoJT7-aRIo0vHD_V8QFvqtYz1AkK_Q';
        const _supabase = supabase.createClient(url, key);
        try {
            const { data: calendarData, error } = await _supabase
                .from('Calendar')
                .select('*');

            if (error) {
                throw error;
            }

            let tableHtml = '<table class="table table-striped"><thead><tr><th>Email</th><th>Telefon</th><th>Lokacija</th><th>Slike</th><th>Snimak</th><th>Dron</th><th>Vreme</th><th>Poslato</th><th>Status</th></tr></thead><tbody>';

            calendarData.forEach(entry => {
                tableHtml += '<tr>';
                tableHtml += `<td>${entry.email}</td>`;
                tableHtml += `<td>${entry.telefon}</td>`;
                tableHtml += `<td>${entry.lokacija}</td>`;
                tableHtml += `<td>${entry.slike}</td>`;
                tableHtml += `<td>${entry.snimak}</td>`;
                tableHtml += `<td>${entry.dron}</td>`;
                tableHtml += `<td>${entry.vreme}</td>`;
                tableHtml += `<td>${entry.created_at}</td>`;
                tableHtml += '<td>';
                tableHtml += `<select onchange="updateStatus(this, '${entry.id}')">`;
                if (entry.status === null) {
                    tableHtml += '<option value="" selected disabled hidden>Izaberite status</option>';
                }
                tableHtml += `<option value="prihvacen" ${entry.status === 'prihvacen' ? 'selected' : ''}>Prihvaćen</option>`;
                tableHtml += `<option value="odbijen" ${entry.status === 'odbijen' ? 'selected' : ''}>Odbijen</option>`;
                tableHtml += `</select>`;
                tableHtml += '</td>';
                tableHtml += '</tr>';
            });

            tableHtml += '</tbody></table>';

            document.getElementById('calendar-table').innerHTML = tableHtml;
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error loading calendar data:', error);
            alert('Error loading calendar data: ' + error.message);
        }
    }

    async function updateStatus(selectElement, id) {
        const newStatus = selectElement.value;
        const url = 'https://kvxswebzyfogzgiclagy.supabase.co';
        const key = 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJzdXBhYmFzZSIsInJlZiI6Imt2eHN3ZWJ6eWZvZ3pnaWNsYWd5Iiwicm9sZSI6ImFub24iLCJpYXQiOjE3MDg0NjA5NDcsImV4cCI6MjAyNDAzNjk0N30.hLJFmnkA-2oNgXoJT7-aRIo0vHD_V8QFvqtYz1AkK_Q';
        const _supabase = supabase.createClient(url, key);
        try {
            const { data, error } = await _supabase
                .from('Calendar')
                .update({ status: newStatus })
                .eq('id', id);
            if (error) {
                throw error;
            }
            console.log('Status updated successfully:', data);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error updating status:', error);
            alert('Error updating status: ' + error.message);
        }
    }
    loadCalendarTable();


    function navbar() {
        var navbar = document.querySelector('.navbar');
        var logoContainer = document.querySelector('.logo-container');
        navbar.classList.add('sticky');
        logoContainer.classList.add('hide-logo');
    }
    navbar();
</script>

...

<script>
    async function loadPuzzleTable() {
        const url = 'https://kvxswebzyfogzgiclagy.supabase.co';
        const key = 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJzdXBhYmFzZSIsInJlZiI6Imt2eHN3ZWJ6eWZvZ3pnaWNsYWd5Iiwicm9sZSI6ImFub24iLCJpYXQiOjE3MDg0NjA5NDcsImV4cCI6MjAyNDAzNjk0N30.hLJFmnkA-2oNgXoJT7-aRIo0vHD_V8QFvqtYz1AkK_Q';
        const _supabase = supabase.createClient(url, key);
        try {
            const { data: puzzleData, error } = await _supabase
                .from('puzzle')
                .select('*');

            if (error) {
                throw error;
            }

            let tableHtml = '<table class="table table-striped"><thead><tr><th>Email</th><th>Username</th><th>Cena</th><th>Telefon</th><th>Image URL</th><th>Created At</th><th>Vrsta proizvoda</th><th>Status proizvoda</th></tr></thead><tbody>';

            puzzleData.forEach(entry => {
                tableHtml += '<tr>';
                tableHtml += `<td>${entry.email}</td>`;
                tableHtml += `<td>${entry.username}</td>`;
                tableHtml += `<td>${entry.cena}</td>`;
                tableHtml += `<td>${entry.telefon}</td>`;
                tableHtml += `<td><img src="${entry.image_url}" alt="Slika" style="max-width: 250px; max-height: 150px;"></td>`;
                tableHtml += `<td>${entry.created_at}</td>`;
                tableHtml += `<td>${entry.sorta}</td>`;
                tableHtml += '<td>';
                tableHtml += `<select onchange="updateStatus(this, '${entry.id}')">`;
                if (entry.status === null) {
                    tableHtml += '<option value="" selected disabled hidden>Izaberite status</option>';
                }
                tableHtml += `<option value="prihvacen" ${entry.status === 'prihvacen' ? 'selected' : ''}>Prihvaćen</option>`;
                tableHtml += `<option value="odbijen" ${entry.status === 'odbijen' ? 'selected' : ''}>Odbijen</option>`;
                tableHtml += `</select>`;
                tableHtml += '</td>';
               // tableHtml += '</td>';
            });

            tableHtml += '</tbody></table>';

            document.getElementById('puzzle-table').innerHTML = tableHtml;
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error loading puzzle data:', error);
            alert('Error loading puzzle data: ' + error.message);
        }
    }


    async function updateStatus(selectElement, id) {
        const newStatus = selectElement.value;
        const url = 'https://kvxswebzyfogzgiclagy.supabase.co';
        const key = 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJzdXBhYmFzZSIsInJlZiI6Imt2eHN3ZWJ6eWZvZ3pnaWNsYWd5Iiwicm9sZSI6ImFub24iLCJpYXQiOjE3MDg0NjA5NDcsImV4cCI6MjAyNDAzNjk0N30.hLJFmnkA-2oNgXoJT7-aRIo0vHD_V8QFvqtYz1AkK_Q';
        const _supabase = supabase.createClient(url, key);
        try {
            const { data, error } = await _supabase
                .from('puzzle')
                .update({ status: newStatus })
                .eq('id', id);
            if (error) {
                throw error;
            }
            console.log('Status updated successfully:', data);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error updating status:', error);
            alert('Error updating status: ' + error.message);
        }
    }


    loadPuzzleTable();
</script>

    <?php
/*
require 'phpmailer/src/Exception.php';
require 'phpmailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
require 'phpmailer/src/SMTP.php';

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
*/
?>



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Fotografski studio Dunjic</title>
    <link href="css.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.8/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-I7E8VVD/ismYTF4hNIPjVp/Zjvgyol6VFvRkX/vR+Vc4jQkC+hVqc2pM8ODewa9r" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-BBtl+eGJRgqQAUMxJ7pMwbEyER4l1g+O15P+16Ep7Q9Q+zqX6gSbd85u4mG4QzX+" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/941d123c2d.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@supabase/supabase-js@2"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body class="dark">
<?php include "1navbar.php"; ?>




<h1 class="heading" style="text-align: center;
                            margin-top: 120px;">
    Admin panel
</h1>




<div id="calendar-table" style="margin-top: 50px;"></div>




<div id="puzzle-table" style="margin-top: 100px;"></div>




<script>
    async function loadCalendarTable() {
        const url = 'https://kvxswebzyfogzgiclagy.supabase.co';
        const key = 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJzdXBhYmFzZSIsInJlZiI6Imt2eHN3ZWJ6eWZvZ3pnaWNsYWd5Iiwicm9sZSI6ImFub24iLCJpYXQiOjE3MDg0NjA5NDcsImV4cCI6MjAyNDAzNjk0N30.hLJFmnkA-2oNgXoJT7-aRIo0vHD_V8QFvqtYz1AkK_Q';
        const _supabase = supabase.createClient(url, key);
        try {
            const { data: calendarData, error } = await _supabase
                .from('Calendar')
                .select('*');

            if (error) {
                throw error;
            }

            let tableHtml = '<table class="table table-striped"><thead><tr><th>Email</th><th>Telefon</th><th>Lokacija</th><th>Slike</th><th>Snimak</th><th>Dron</th><th>Vreme</th><th>Poslato</th><th>Status</th></tr></thead><tbody>';

            calendarData.forEach(entry => {
                tableHtml += '<tr>';
                tableHtml += `<td>${entry.email}</td>`;
                tableHtml += `<td>${entry.telefon}</td>`;
                tableHtml += `<td>${entry.lokacija}</td>`;
                tableHtml += `<td>${entry.slike}</td>`;
                tableHtml += `<td>${entry.snimak}</td>`;
                tableHtml += `<td>${entry.dron}</td>`;
                tableHtml += `<td>${entry.vreme}</td>`;
                tableHtml += `<td>${entry.created_at}</td>`;
                tableHtml += '<td>';
                tableHtml += `<select onchange="updateStatus(this, '${entry.id}')">`;
                if (entry.status === null) {
                    tableHtml += '<option value="" selected disabled hidden>Izaberite status</option>';
                }
                tableHtml += `<option value="prihvacen" ${entry.status === 'prihvacen' ? 'selected' : ''}>Prihvaćen</option>`;
                tableHtml += `<option value="odbijen" ${entry.status === 'odbijen' ? 'selected' : ''}>Odbijen</option>`;
                tableHtml += `</select>`;
                tableHtml += '</td>';
                tableHtml += '</tr>';
            });

            tableHtml += '</tbody></table>';

            document.getElementById('calendar-table').innerHTML = tableHtml;
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error loading calendar data:', error);
            alert('Error loading calendar data: ' + error.message);
        }
    }






    async function updateStatus(selectElement, id) {
        const newStatus = selectElement.value;
       const email = selectElement.parentElement.parentElement.querySelector('td:first-child').textContent;
        const selectedOptionText = selectElement.options[selectElement.selectedIndex].text; 


        const url = 'https://kvxswebzyfogzgiclagy.supabase.co';
        const key = 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJzdXBhYmFzZSIsInJlZiI6Imt2eHN3ZWJ6eWZvZ3pnaWNsYWd5Iiwicm9sZSI6ImFub24iLCJpYXQiOjE3MDg0NjA5NDcsImV4cCI6MjAyNDAzNjk0N30.hLJFmnkA-2oNgXoJT7-aRIo0vHD_V8QFvqtYz1AkK_Q';
        const _supabase = supabase.createClient(url, key);
        try {
            const { data, error } = await _supabase
                .from('Calendar')
                .update({ status: newStatus })
                .eq('id', id);
            if (error) {
                throw error;
            }




           // sendEmail(data.email, newStatus); // Poziv funkcije za slanje mejla
        // AJAX poziv ka PHP skripti sendEmail.php
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'send.php',
                data:  {

                    email: email,
                    newStatus: newStatus,
                    subject:'Ažuriran status kalendara',
                    message: `Vaš termin za venčanje je ažuriran u: ${selectedOptionText}`

                    },
                success: function(response) {
                    console.log('Email poslat: ' + response);
                },
                error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                    console.error('Greška prilikom slanja emaila:', error);
                }
            });




            console.log('Status updated successfully:', data);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error updating status:', error);
            alert('Error updating status: ' + error.message);
        }
    }
    loadCalendarTable();




    function navbar() {
        var navbar = document.querySelector('.navbar');
        var logoContainer = document.querySelector('.logo-container');
        navbar.classList.add('sticky');
        logoContainer.classList.add('hide-logo');
    }
    navbar();
</script>
















<script>
    async function loadPuzzleTable() {
        const url = 'https://kvxswebzyfogzgiclagy.supabase.co';
        const key = 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJzdXBhYmFzZSIsInJlZiI6Imt2eHN3ZWJ6eWZvZ3pnaWNsYWd5Iiwicm9sZSI6ImFub24iLCJpYXQiOjE3MDg0NjA5NDcsImV4cCI6MjAyNDAzNjk0N30.hLJFmnkA-2oNgXoJT7-aRIo0vHD_V8QFvqtYz1AkK_Q';
        const _supabase = supabase.createClient(url, key);
        try {
            const { data: puzzleData, error } = await _supabase
                .from('puzzle')
                .select('*');

            if (error) {
                throw error;
            }

            let tableHtml = '<table class="table table-striped"><thead><tr><th>Email</th><th>Username</th><th>Cena</th><th>Telefon</th><th>Image URL</th><th>Created At</th><th>Vrsta proizvoda</th><th>Status proizvoda</th></tr></thead><tbody>';

            puzzleData.forEach(entry => {
                tableHtml += '<tr>';
                tableHtml += `<td>${entry.email}</td>`;
                tableHtml += `<td>${entry.username}</td>`;
                tableHtml += `<td>${entry.cena}</td>`;
                tableHtml += `<td>${entry.telefon}</td>`;
                tableHtml += `<td><img src="${entry.image_url}" alt="Slika" style="max-width: 250px; max-height: 150px;"></td>`;
                tableHtml += `<td>${entry.created_at}</td>`;
                tableHtml += `<td>${entry.sorta}</td>`;
                tableHtml += '<td>';
                tableHtml += `<select onchange="updateStatus(this, '${entry.id}')">`;
                if (entry.status === null) {
                    tableHtml += '<option value="" selected disabled hidden>Izaberite status</option>';
                }
                tableHtml += `<option value="prihvacen" ${entry.status === 'prihvacen' ? 'selected' : ''}>Prihvaćen</option>`;
                tableHtml += `<option value="odbijen" ${entry.status === 'odbijen' ? 'selected' : ''}>Odbijen</option>`;
                tableHtml += `</select>`;
                tableHtml += '</td>';
               // tableHtml += '</td>';
            });

            tableHtml += '</tbody></table>';

            document.getElementById('puzzle-table').innerHTML = tableHtml;
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error loading puzzle data:', error);
            alert('Error loading puzzle data: ' + error.message);
        }
    }



    async function updateStatus(selectElement, id) {
        const newStatus = selectElement.value;
        const email = selectElement.parentElement.parentElement.querySelector('td:first-child').textContent;
        const selectedOptionText = selectElement.options[selectElement.selectedIndex].text; 


        const url = 'https://kvxswebzyfogzgiclagy.supabase.co';
        const key = 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJzdXBhYmFzZSIsInJlZiI6Imt2eHN3ZWJ6eWZvZ3pnaWNsYWd5Iiwicm9sZSI6ImFub24iLCJpYXQiOjE3MDg0NjA5NDcsImV4cCI6MjAyNDAzNjk0N30.hLJFmnkA-2oNgXoJT7-aRIo0vHD_V8QFvqtYz1AkK_Q';
        const _supabase = supabase.createClient(url, key);
        try {
            const { data, error } = await _supabase
                .from('puzzle')
                .update({ status: newStatus })
                .eq('id', id);
            if (error) {
                throw error;
            }




         //   sendEmail(data.email, newStatus); // Poziv funkcije za slanje mejla
         // AJAX poziv ka PHP skripti sendEmail.php
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'send.php',
            data:  {

                email: email,
                newStatus: newStatus,
                subject:'Ažuriran status proizvoda',
                message: `Vaš zahtev za proizvod je ažuriran u: ${selectedOptionText}`

                    },
            success: function(response) {
                console.log('Email poslat: ' + response);
            },
            error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                console.error('Greška prilikom slanja emaila:', error);
            }
        });





            console.log('Status updated successfully:', data);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error updating status:', error);
            alert('Error updating status: ' + error.message);
        }
    }






    loadPuzzleTable();


<?php
/*
    function sendEmail($email, $newStatus) {
    $mail = new PHPMailer(true);

    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->Username = 'dunjikfoto@gmail.com';
    $mail->Password = 'Malikira123';
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
    $mail->Port = 465;

    $mail->setFrom('dunjikfoto@gmail.com');
    $mail->addAddress($email);
    $mail->isHTML(true);
    $mail->Subject = 'Status Update';
    $mail->Body = 'Vaš status je ažuriran u: ' . $newStatus;

    $mail->send();

    echo
    "
    <script>
    alert('Vaša poruka je poslata!');
    window.location.href = 'admin.php';
    </script>
    ";
}
*/
?>

</script>







<?php include "ytlogin.php"; ?>
<?php include "1footer.php"; ?>








*/


Can you edit in yesterdays code as well so that both codes can be compared? Or just the diff between the two?

I edited it now, i hope this can help solve my problem :/

Looking at the code, I think it can help you that you reduce it so that it is easier to compare for you. identify the parts that are actually different.

only ajax part and those lines in comments at the beggining and the end are different, its not that much different but like i said, yesterday first code worked without any problem then i added this ajax part with another php file for function for sending email and it didnt work there so i removed all changes and stuff but got this warning and it wont change its value in supabase. In the meantime i fixed this php thing for sending emails but it still wont change value in supabase

Well then it's maybe what the diagnostic message tells about: may not work (undefined means that you can not purposefully use it the same all the time for the same outcome, like behaving the same all the time). Not knowing Supabase much, but as this looks to me it's in the Javascript part, reduce it to a single instance only. You've perhaps duplicated it for creating the second version and forgot to remove it when you restored it? In the future I'd recommend a version control system and clean backups so that you can actually restore (go back in time).
